# Android Studio 'forgetting' that layout files exist

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Noob *Android Studio 3.6.1 on Mac Mojave* developer here. I have a very simple app with a few activities. Every so often, the Kotlin class for one of the activities will complain of an unresolved reference to the corresponding layout XML file.

For example, in the Kotlin Class (TraceActivity.kt), I have the following code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_trace)
```

and the corresponding XML file lives at:

```
MyApp/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_trace.xml
```

All pretty standard stuff I reckon. But `setContentView` would complain that it couldn't resolve `activity_trace`. This has happened on a few occasions, and I discovered that restarting would resolve the problem. But this morning, it isn't helping. And it's also started complaining about some of the strings I've added to `strings.xml`

I managed to get round the errors by making use of the full names for each of the items e.g.

```
com.mysite.myapp.R.layout.activity_trace
```

and

```
com.mysite.myapp.R.string.my_message
```

So my guess (as a noob) that somewhere it's losing track of where it is. And yet my other activities are perfectly happy when I omit the full location. Can anyone offer some insight here? Thank you - SO is awesome.

Comment: Rebuild and clean the project. Sometimes references does not update.

Comment: Thank you Haseeb - it seems happy again now. I am surprised that the content of my very small app is complex enough to get out of sync like that. Many thanks!